# Android - Dynamically Create Controls in AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm working on getting a better handle on `AsyncTask` and am trying to create controls dynamically with asyncTask's `onPostExecute()`.

The code I have below does work and it creates controls, but is there a way to loop this, but delay it so that variable I is incremented after the asynctask completes?

I've read through using the get() method, but I can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone advise how to either wait till a background task is complete or some other way to dynamically create controls based on a variable number?

```
package com.example.dynamicallycreatecontrols;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            Integer i = 0;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                            while (i < 5) {
                                                            new createControl().execute(i);
                                                            i++;
                            }

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                            return true;
            }


            //asynctask
            public class createControl extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Button> {


                            Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.llMain);
                            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            protected void onPreExecute(Integer i) {
                                            // nothing right now
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected Button doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            // do the calculation

                                            return null;
                            }

                            protected void onPostExecute(Button v) {
                                            // build the controls here
                                            btn.setText("Play" + i);
                                            ll.addView(btn, lp);
                                            SystemClock.sleep(1000);

                            }


            }

}
```

I'm new to android development and java so i'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding a concept of get() or if there is a better way to do this all together.

Thanks for any time allocated in assistance.

-nick

Comment: If you don't do any heavy work before creating buttons, there is no need to use AsyncTask at all.

Comment: @vovkab the main app i am working on downloads a file list from the internet and uses that to load sample music for the user to listen to.  so there is heavy work that needs to be done before the buttons are created.

so far what i can find is there is no way to pause or delay an asynctask.  so i'm looking at using handlers, but that isn't much help either...

Comment: So you have to use AsyncTask, do all network work in doInBackground. and update your buttons or ListView in onPostExecute. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

When `doInBackground()` done I move to `onPostExecute()`. I don't need any delays there.  When I call `task.execute(/**/)` actually I invoke `doInBackground()` async task and I don't care when it finish but I know that I have callback `onPostExecute()` and I wait and update my main Thread from there.

To make it clearer lets say you have application where user wants to register to server and update GUI led to green color. User presses on button and calls method `registerClient()`

This method runs:

```
private void registerClient(){
...
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Connecting. Please wait...", true);
HeavyTask task = new HeavyTask();
task.execute(user, password, domain);   
}
```

So what we have in `HeavyTask`:

```
private class HeavyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private String username = "";
        private String domain = "";
        private String password = "";

            // run async task 
        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {         

            username = args[0];
            password = args[1];
            domain = args[2];               

            registerClientToServer(username, password, domain, null);               

            return null;
        } 

            protected void onPostExecute(Void results) {

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                 
                updateGUI(username, domain);                    
            }
        }, 500);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an object and instantiate it? You can control if the object exists or if it already finished what he had to do.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      private createControl cc = null;
      Integer i = 0;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        while (i < 5) {
                             if (cc == null){
                                  cc = new createControl();
                                  cc.execute(i);
                                  i++;
                             }
                        }
        }

 ...
```

}

Then in `onPostExecute` just add `cc = null;`

Comment: The main reason I'm trying to do it this way is because the number of controls will be based on a number of sample songs that a local band will upload to their server and their app will download.
So i'm trying to sort a way to stream the mp3s and create controls for each one, like a list of sample songs, each with their own control.

Does that make sense?